# Native Query resulting in error only in H2 database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, h2

I have a query that runs on MySQL databases but not on h2.

This is my repository:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT r.* FROM rewards r "
      + "INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  "
      + "WHERE m.printer_family = :businessPrinterFamily "
      + "AND r.reward_type IN (:rewardTypes) "
      + "AND IF(:isOpportunities, m.model_pk IN (:businessPrinterModels), TRUE) "
      + "ORDER BY :sortingMethod",
      countQuery = "SELECT r.* FROM rewards r "
          + "INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  "
          + "WHERE m.printer_family = :businessPrinterFamily "
          + "AND r.reward_type IN (:rewardTypes) "
          + "AND IF(:isOpportunities, m.model_pk IN (:businessPrinterModels), TRUE) ",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<Reward> getFilteredRewards(@Param("sortingMethod") String sortingMethod,
      @Param("isOpportunities") boolean isOpportunities,
      @Param("businessPrinterModels") List<Integer> businessPrinterModels,
      @Param("rewardTypes") List<Integer> rewardTypes,
      @Param("businessPrinterFamily") int businessPrinterFamily, Pageable pageable);
```

But only on h2 I get the following error:

```
could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND [*]IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ?"; expected "INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ? [42001-214]
```

In the logs I get the following:

```
2022-09-15 09:35:15.647 ERROR 267713 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND [*]IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ?"; expected "INTERSECTS (, NOT, EXISTS, UNIQUE, INTERSECTS"; SQL statement:
SELECT r.* FROM rewards r INNER JOIN models m ON r.model_id = m.model_pk  WHERE m.printer_family = ? AND r.reward_type IN (?, ?) AND IF(?, m.model_pk IN (?), TRUE) ORDER BY ? limit ? [42001-214]
```

My h2 database is configured as follows:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: false
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

Any ideas of whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [H2 MySQL compatibility mode](https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=compatibility&search=compat#compatibility) doesn't mention anything about an `IF()` function support. Your options are (at least):

- [Request it from H2](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/new)
- Replace `IF(a, b, c)` by standard SQL `CASE WHEN a THEN b ELSE c END`
- Use testcontainers to run integration tests directly on MySQL rather than on H2 ([I've blogged about this here, as I highly recommend it, irrespective of the ORM used](https://blog.jooq.org/using-h2-as-a-test-database-product/))
- Use a [SQL translator like jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/using-jooq-to-write-vendor-agnostic-sql-with-jpas-native-query-or-formula/) to translate your native SQL to the target dialect, under the hood. Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ

The quickest fix is to use `CASE`. But personally, I recommend integration testing directly on MySQL, unless you're using H2 also as a production database product.